# Localstorage doesn't count to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, nan

We're trying to make a quiz (that you can play offline) everytime you go further you get a new question. (when the page reloads you get the next question) The thing is, the page keeps loading the first question and we really don't know why.

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Europa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../foyer.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1, minimal-scale=1">
    <script src="../../../jquery/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body class="europafotobodyquiz">

    <img id="homequiz" src="../../../pics/home.png" onclick="window.location.href='../../../startscherm/index.html'">

    <h4 id="vraag">Wat is vreemd / verkeerd in België?</h4>

    <div id="antwoorden">
        <form onclick="window.location.href='../../antwoord/index.html'">
            <button id="antwoord1" type="button" class="antwoordmogelijkheid" correct>Een hekel hebben aan iemand met een andere huidskleur</button>
            <button id="antwoord2" type="button" class="antwoordmogelijkheid">Neus snuiten in een zakdoek</button>
            <button id="antwoord3" type="button" class="antwoordmogelijkheid">Oma of opa woont in een rusthuis</button>
            <button id="antwoord4" type="button" class="antwoordmogelijkheid">Varkensvlees eten</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="page-count">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.antwoordmogelijkheid').click(function (e) {
                    if ($(this).attr("correct") == undefined) {

                        $('.antwoordmogelijkheid').css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)');

                    } else {

                        $('.antwoordmogelijkheid').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)');

                    }

                });

                if (localStorage.pagecount) {

                    localStorage.pagecount = Number(localStorage.pagecount) + 1;

                    if (localStorage.pagecount == 2) {

                        document.getElementById("antwoord2").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord3").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord4").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById('antwoord1').setAttribute("correct", "");

                        $('#vraag').text("Wat is niet waar?");
                        $('#antwoord1').text('Alleen belgen mogen bij het Belgisch elftal voetballen');
                        $('#antwoord2').text('Vlees etende planten eten vlees');
                        $('#antwoord3').text('Sinaasappels zijn oranje');
                        $('#antwoord4').text('Niet alle vogels kunnen vliegen');
                    } else if (localStorage.pagecount == 3) {

                        document.getElementById("antwoord1").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord2").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord4").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById('antwoord3').setAttribute("correct", "");

                        $('#vraag').text("Als in België iemand bevalt, wordt er vaak een dier op het geboortekaartje of een kartonnen figuur ervan in de tuin gezet. Weet jij welk dier dit is?");
                        $('#antwoord1').text('Een leeuw');
                        $('#antwoord2').text('Een panter');
                        $('#antwoord3').text('Een ooievaar');
                        $('#antwoord4').text('Een olifant');
                    } else if (localStorage.pagecount == 4) {

                        document.getElementById("antwoord1").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord2").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord4").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById('antwoord3').setAttribute("correct", "");

                        $('#vraag').text("Hoeveel koeien leven er ongeveer in Brussel");
                        $('#antwoord1').text('10');
                        $('#antwoord2').text('100');
                        $('#antwoord3').text('1000');
                        $('#antwoord4').text('geen');
                    } else if (localStorage.pagecount == 5) {

                        document.getElementById("antwoord1").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord2").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord3").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById('antwoord4').setAttribute("correct", "");

                        $('#vraag').text("Weet jij waarom Grieken soms driemaal spugen?");
                        $('#antwoord1').text('Tegen de warmte');
                        $('#antwoord2').text('Om dank je te zeggen');
                        $('#antwoord3').text('Om hallo te zeggen');
                        $('#antwoord4').text('Tegen de duivel en ongeluk');
                    } else if (localStorage.pagecount == 6) {

                        document.getElementById("antwoord1").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord3").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord4").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById('antwoord2').setAttribute("correct", "");

                        $('#vraag').text("In België is er geen dictatuur, wie bepaalt er die wetten in België?");
                        $('#antwoord1').text('Enkel de Koning');
                        $('#antwoord2').text('Het parlement samen met de Koning');
                        $('#antwoord3').text('Enkel het parlement');
                        $('#antwoord4').text('Enkel de rechters');
                    } else if (localStorage.pagecount == 7) {

                        document.getElementById("antwoord1").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord3").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord4").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById('antwoord2').setAttribute("correct", "");

                        $('#vraag').text("België is een democratie. Wat is geen kenmerk van een democratie?");
                        $('#antwoord1').text('Er zijn vrij verkiezingen');
                        $('#antwoord2').text('Er is maar 1 partij');
                        $('#antwoord3').text('Je mag je eigen mening zeggen');
                        $('#antwoord4').text('De stem van het volk telt');
                    } else if (localStorage.pagecount == 8) {

                        document.getElementById("antwoord1").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord2").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord3").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById('antwoord4').setAttribute("correct", "");

                        $('#vraag').text("Rond hoe laat eten Italianen hun avondeten?");
                        $('#antwoord1').text('18 uur');
                        $('#antwoord2').text('19 uur 30');
                        $('#antwoord3').text('17 uur');
                        $('#antwoord4').text('21 uur 30');
                    } else if (localStorage.pagecount == 9) {

                        document.getElementById("antwoord4").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord3").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord2").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById('antwoord1').setAttribute("correct", "");

                        $('#vraag').text("Hoeveel kussen geven Spanjaarden elkaar om te begroeten?");
                        $('#antwoord1').text('2');
                        $('#antwoord2').text('3');
                        $('#antwoord3').text('1');
                        $('#antwoord4').text('4');
                    } else if (localStorage.pagecount == 10) {

                        document.getElementById("antwoord1").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord2").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById("antwoord4").removeAttribute("correct");
                        document.getElementById('antwoord3').setAttribute("correct", "");

                        $('#vraag').text("Hoe worden achternamen in Ijsland gekozen?");
                        $('#antwoord1').text('De achternaam van de moeder');
                        $('#antwoord2').text('De achternaam van de vader');
                        $('#antwoord3').text('Ze hebben geen achternamen');
                        $('#antwoord4').text('De achternaam van de vader én de moeder');
                    } else if (localStorage.pagecount == 11) {

                        $('html').hide();

                        localStorage.clear();

                        window.location.href = "../../../wistjedatje/index.html";

                    }

                    console.log(localStorage.pagecount);

                } else {

                    localStorage.pagecount = 1;
                    console.log("test");

                }

            })
        </script>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're loading jQuery 1.12.3 twice in your `<head>`

Comment: Have you tried console logging `localStorage.getItem('pagecount')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try like

To set value in pageCount.

```
localStorage.setItem("pageCount", 1);
```

To get value of pageCount.

```
localStorage.getItem("pageCount");
```